# Why do HRs specially in India not follow up with the candidates after the interview?

Tags: human-resources, india

I have had few chances where the interview goes good but the HR reps mostly just don't follow up nor do they reply back to the emails/calls. I am not sure about other countries but it is quite common here in India, all the while the candidate would have taken a day-off from work to travel to the interview location or spent some good time in preparing for the interview.

Are the HR reps really that busy that they cannot reply a follow up mail stating that you have been rejected  for reason x,y,z.

Comment: Sounds more like a rant but it is not about being busy or being in India. Companies do respond back (in India as well !) but once in a while there are people who are not very professional or motivated. Happens across humanity irrespective of their nationality.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said – Human Resources. They don’t have enough human resources.

It’s rude, of course, and it wouldn’t take too much effort to send a canned reply to candidates in whom they are not currently interested. Alas, it has become the norm.

But, how often do you get back to people or companies that you have lost interest in? Just think of those friends whom you have been meaning to email for months.   You may have the best intentions to do so, but human nature being what it is other things that ***need*** to be done can get in the way and you never get round to it until it is so late that it might be awkward or look rude to do so. Sound familiar? :-)

That being said, many do reply to non-accepted candidates. I have done so myself, especially when they are what I am looking for -  but not right now as I have no current openings -  but I would like to leave them with a good impression and encourage them to try again at a later date, or say that we will keep in touch.